# Show data in datatable in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatable

I have page called cash-flow.  I want to show the data which I fetched from db using ajax. I have recieved data but is not showing in view. what is the problem please guide. 
 this is my view file

```
                       <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-body">
                @can('account.access')
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="cash_flow_table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>@lang( 'messages.date' )</th>
                                <th>@lang( 'account.account' )</th>
                                <th>@lang( 'lang_v1.description' )</th>
                                <th>@lang('account.credit')</th>
                                <th>@lang('account.debit')</th>
                                <th>@lang( 'lang_v1.balance' )</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                @endcan
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


 <div class="modal fade account_model" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel">
</div>

        </section>
         <!-- /.content -->

              @endsection

              @section('javascript')
                 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    dateRangeSettings.autoUpdateInput = false
    $('#transaction_date_range').daterangepicker(
        dateRangeSettings,
        function (start, end) {
            $('#transaction_date_range').val(start.format(moment_date_format) + ' ~ ' + end.format(moment_date_format));
            var start = '';
            var end = '';
            if($('#transaction_date_range').val()){
                start = $('input#transaction_date_range').data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                end = $('input#transaction_date_range').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            }
            cash_flow_table.ajax.reload();
        }
    );

    // Cash Flow Table
    cash_flow_table = $('#cash_flow_table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        "ajax": {
                "url": "{{action("AccountController@cashFlow")}}",
                "data": function ( d ) {
                    var start = '';
                    var end = '';
                    if($('#transaction_date_range').val() != ''){
                        start = $('#transaction_date_range').data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        end = $('#transaction_date_range').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    }

                    d.account_id = $('#account_id').val();
                    d.type = $('#transaction_type').val();
                    d.start_date = start,
                    d.end_date = end
                }
            },
        "ordering": false,
        "searching": false,
        columns: [
            {data: 'operation_date', name: 'operation_date'},
            {data: 'account_name', name: 'account_name'},
            {data: 'sub_type', name: 'sub_type'},
            {data: 'credit', name: 'amount'},
            {data: 'debit', name: 'amount'},
            {data: 'balance', name: 'balance'},
        ],
        "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
            __currency_convert_recursively($('#cash_flow_table'));
        }
    });
    $('#transaction_type, #account_id').change( function(){
        cash_flow_table.ajax.reload();
    });
    $('#transaction_date_range').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $('#transaction_date_range').val('').change();
        cash_flow_table.ajax.reload();
    });

           });
                </script>
```

This is the function of controller which fetched data

```
public function cashFlow()
{


    if (!auth()->user()->can('account.access')) {
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }

    $business_id = request()->session()->get('user.business_id');





        $accounts = AccountTransaction::join(
            'accounts as A',
            'account_transactions.account_id',
            '=',
            'A.id'
        )
                        ->where('A.business_id', $business_id)
                        ->with(['transaction', 'transaction.contact', 'transfer_transaction'])
                        ->select(['type', 'amount', 'operation_date',
                            'sub_type', 'transfer_transaction_id',
                            DB::raw('(SELECT SUM(IF(AT.type="credit", AT.amount, -1 * AT.amount)) from account_transactions as AT WHERE AT.operation_date <= account_transactions.operation_date AND AT.deleted_at IS NULL) as balance'),
                            'transaction_id',
                            'account_transactions.id',
                            'A.name as account_name'
                            ])
                         ->groupBy('account_transactions.id')
                         ->orderBy('account_transactions.operation_date', 'desc')->get();


        if (!empty(request()->input('type'))) {
            $accounts->where('type', request()->input('type'));
        }

        if (!empty(request()->input('account_id'))) {
            $accounts->where('A.id', request()->input('account_id'));
        }

        $start_date = request()->input('start_date');
        $end_date = request()->input('end_date');

        if (!empty($start_date) && !empty($end_date)) {
            $accounts->whereBetween(DB::raw('date(operation_date)'), [$start_date, $end_date]);

     }

        return DataTables::of($accounts)
                        ->addColumn('debit', function ($row) {
                            if ($row->type == 'debit') {
                                return '<span class="display_currency" data-currency_symbol="true">' . $row->amount . '</span>';
                            }
                            return '';
                        })
                        ->addColumn('credit', function ($row) {
                            if ($row->type == 'credit') {
                                return '<span class="display_currency" data-currency_symbol="true">' . $row->amount . '</span>';
                            }
                            return '';
                        })
                        ->editColumn('balance', function ($row) {
                            return '<span class="display_currency" data-currency_symbol="true">' . $row->balance . '</span>';
                        })
                        ->editColumn('operation_date', function ($row) {
                            return $this->commonUtil->format_date($row->operation_date, true);
                        })
                        ->editColumn('sub_type', function ($row) {
                            $details = '';
                            if (!empty($row->sub_type)) {
                                $details = __('account.' . $row->sub_type);
                                if (in_array($row->sub_type, ['fund_transfer', 'deposit']) && !empty($row->transfer_transaction)) {
                                    if ($row->type == 'credit') {
                                        $details .= ' ( ' . __('account.from') .': ' . $row->transfer_transaction->account->name . ')';
                                    } else {
                                        $details .= ' ( ' . __('account.to') .': ' . $row->transfer_transaction->account->name . ')';
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (!empty($row->transaction->type)) {
                                    if ($row->transaction->type == 'purchase') {
                                        $details = '<b>' . __('purchase.supplier') . ':</b> ' . $row->transaction->contact->name . '<br><b>'.
                                        __('purchase.ref_no') . ':</b> ' . $row->transaction->ref_no;
                                    } elseif ($row->transaction->type == 'sell') {
                                        $details = '<b>' . __('contact.customer') . ':</b> ' . $row->transaction->contact->name . '<br><b>'.
                                        __('sale.invoice_no') . ':</b> ' . $row->transaction->invoice_no;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            return $details;

                        })
                        ->removeColumn('id')
                        ->rawColumns(['credit', 'debit', 'balance', 'sub_type'])
                        ->make(true);



    $accounts = Account::forDropdown($business_id, false);


    $accounts->prepend(__('messages.all'), '');

    return view('account.cash_flow')
             ->with(compact('accounts'));
}
```

it show me following data in browser but not in view.What is wrong please guide

```
         {"draw":0,"recordsTotal":3,"recordsFiltered":3,"data":[{"type":"credit","amount":"10000.0000","operation_date":"01\/16\/2020 23:07","sub_type":"Opening Balance","transfer_transaction_id":null,"balance":"<span class=\"display_currency\" data-currency_symbol=\"true\">12726.7500<\/span>","transaction_id":null,"account_name":"bank name","transaction":null,"transfer_transaction":null,"debit":"","credit":"<span class=\"display_currency\" data-currency_symbol=\"true\">10000.0000<\/span>"},{"type":"credit","amount":"123.0000","operation_date":"01\/16\/2020 23:02","sub_type":"Opening Balance","transfer_transaction_id":null,"balance":"<span class=\"display_currency\" data-currency_symbol=\"true\">2726.7500<\/span>","transaction_id":null,"account_name":"Nazmul Huda","transaction":null,"transfer_transaction":null,"debit":"","credit":"<span class=\"display_currency\" data-currency_symbol=\"true\">123.0000<\/span>"},{"type":"credit","amount":"100.0000","operation_date":"01\/16\/2020 22:42","sub_type":"Opening Balance","transfer_transaction_id":null,"balance":"<span class=\"display_currency\" data-currency_symbol=\"true\">2491.7500<\/span>","transaction_id":null,"account_name":"bank name","transaction":null,"transfer_transaction":null,"debit":"","credit":"<span class=\"display_currency\" data-currency_symbol=\"true\">100.0000<\/span>"}],"input":[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your error is in the return function, it should be as follows:

```
return view('account.cash_flow', compact('accounts'));
```